# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from', near 'a', near 'b'. (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to execute this following query in SQL Server and it gives me the following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 122
> Incorrect syntax near 'CompanyCode'.

Also, when running it in VS2008, I get these errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
> Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
> Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

This is the code:

```
Using SearchDS As New DataSet
   Using objDBcommand As New DBCommand
       objDBcommand.CommandText = " select a.*, isNull(b.CalculationType,0) as CalculationType, " & _
            " isnull(b.amountCode,0) as AmountCode, isNull(b.AmountDescription, '') as AmountDescription " & _
            " INTO " & strBasetable & _
            " from( " objDBcommand.CommandText = " select a.*, isNull(b.CalculationType,0) as CalculationType, " & _
            " isnull(b.amountCode,0) as AmountCode, isNull(b.AmountDescription, '') as AmountDescription " & _
            " INTO " & strBasetable & _
            " from( "

      objDBcommand.CommandText &= " select isnull(VEE.TotalDelaysDuration,0) as TotalDays, isnull(VEE.TCE,0 ) as NetProfitEstimated, Comp.CompanyCode, Comp.Description as CompanyDescription, b.AccountCode, b.AccountDescription, " & _
                     " case " & _
                            " when  (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC) > 0 then (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC) " & _
                            " else " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                            " end as AmountDebitBC, " & _
                            " case " & _
                            " when  (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC) < 0 then (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC) " & _
                            " else " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                            " end as AmountCreditBC, " & _
                            " Voy.CharterPartyDate, Voy.VoyageCode, Voy.Description,Voy.TimeCharterInd, Voy.StartDateTime, Voy.LastVoyageTerminationDateTime, H.LastHireDateTime, " & _
                            " CASE  when Voy.TimeCharterInd = " & clsGlobals.NU(1) & " then Voy.Hire " & _
                                " else  case when Voy.TimeCharterInd = " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " then " & _
                                    " case when voy.FreightRate <> " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " then  voy.FreightRate " & _
                                       " else case when voy.TotalFreight <> " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " then voy.TotalFreight " & _
                                    " else  " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                                        " End " & _
                                    " End " & _
                                " End " & _
                            " end as Hire, " & _
                        " case when Voy.TimeCharterInd = " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " then " & _
                            " case when voy.FreightRate <> " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " then " & clsGlobals.NU(1) & _
                              " else case when voy.TotalFreight <> " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " then " & clsGlobals.NU(2) & _
                                " else " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                                " End " & _
                                " End " & _
                        " else " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                        " end ValueFreight, " & _
                           " Voy.Commission, voy.ActualEndDateTime, " & _
                           " BP.Name, " & _
                           " case " & _
                               " when Voy.lastVoyageTerminationDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then (CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))  - CAST(Voy.lastVoyageTerminationDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))) " & _
                               " else 0 " & _
                           " end " & _
                           " AS BallastDays, " & _
                           " isnull( case " & _
                           " when voy.ActualEndDateTime <>  " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then voy.ActualEndDateTime " & _
                           " when voy.EstimatedEndDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then voy.EstimatedEndDateTime " & _
                           " End , 0) as TerminatedDate, " & _
                           " case " & _
                           " when voy.ActualEndDateTime <>  " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                           " when voy.EstimatedEndDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then " & clsGlobals.NU(1) & _
                           " End as ActualOrEstimated, " & _
                           " CASE  when Voy.TimeCharterInd = 1.0  then " & _
                         " case when voy.ActualEndDateTime = " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & _
                           " then " & _
                               " Case when H.LastHireDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & _
                                   " then  CAST(H.LastHireDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))  - CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2)) " & _
                                   "  Else  " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & " End  " & _
                                " else " & _
                               " CAST(voy.ActualEndDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))  - CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))   " & _
                           " End " & _
                          " else " & _
                                   " case when voy.ActualEndDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then " & _
                                        " CAST(Voy.ActualEndDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2)) - CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))" & _
                                   " else " & _
                                       " case when voy.EstimatedEndDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & " then " & _
                                           " CAST(voy.EstimatedEndDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))  - CAST(voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))" & _
                                       " Else " & _
                                            clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                                       " End " & _
                                   "  End " & _
                           " end as 'Voyage Period', " & _
                           " Case " & _
                           " when Voy.TimeCharterInd = " & clsGlobals.NU(1) & " AND H.LastHireDateTime <> " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(clsGlobals.gMINDATE)) & _
                           " Then CAST(H.LastHireDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))  - CAST(lastVoyageTerminationDateTime AS NUMERIC(9,2))  " & _
                           " Else " & clsGlobals.NU(0) & _
                           " end as 'Hire Collected' " & _
                           " FROM voyages voy left outer join VoyagesEstimationHeader VEE on VEE.VoyageCode = voy.Voyagecode and VEE.VesselCode = voy.Vesselcode and VEE.EstimationStatus = '3' " & _
                           " AND VEE.PrevailingInd = (Case when ((select count(*) from VoyagesEstimationHeader where vesselcode = VEE.VesselCode and VoyageCode = VEE.VoyageCode AND EstimationStatus = '3') > 1 ) then  1  " & _
                           " else (select PrevailingInd from VoyagesEstimationHeader where vesselcode = VEE.VesselCode and VoyageCode = VEE.VoyageCode AND EstimationStatus = '3') end ) " & _
                         " LEFT OUTER JOIN BusinessPartners BP ON Voy.ChartererCode = BP.BusinessPartnerCode, " & clsFunctions.GetActualTableName(Me.Name, "Companies") & " Comp, " & _
                         " ( " & _
                         " select Fid.AccountCode, Acc.Description as AccountDescription, FID.SubAccountCode, FID.CompanyCode, " & _
                         " sum( Fid.AmountDebitBC)as 'AmountDebitBC', sum(Fid.AmountCreditBC) as 'AmountCreditBC' " & _
                         " from  FiStatementsDetail FID, FiStatementsHeader FIH, " & clsFunctions.GetActualTableName(Me.Name, "Accounts_1") & " Acc, " & _
                         clsFunctions.GetActualTableName(Me.Name, "Companies") & " Companies " & _
                         " where Fid.AccountCode = acc.AccountCode " & _
                         " And Acc.SubAccountType = " & enmSubAccountType.enmVoyage & _
                         " AND Fid.TransactionType = FiH.TransactionType" & _
                         " AND Fid.TransactionNum = FiH.TransactionNum " & _
                         " AND Fid.FiscalYear = FiH.FiscalYear " & _
                         " AND FiH.TransactionReasonCode NOT IN ( " & strExcludeTransactionReasons & ")" & _
                         " AND FID.CompanyCode = Companies.CompanyCode "

                    If dtpDateFrom.Checked = True Then
                        objDBcommand.CommandText &= " AND FIH.TransactionDate >= " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(dtpDateFrom.Value.Date))
                    End If
                    If dtpDateTo.Checked = True Then
                        objDBcommand.CommandText &= " AND FIH.TransactionDate <= " & clsGlobals.Q(clsGlobals.AD(dtpDateTo.Value.Date))
                    End If

                    objDBcommand.CommandText &= " group by Fid.AccountCode, Acc.Description, FID.SubAccountCode, FID.CompanyCode " & _
                          " ) b, " & _
                          " ( select max(fid.Hiredate)as  LastHireDateTime ,Fid.subAccountCode, FID.CompanyCode " & _
                         " FROM fistatementsDetail fid, " & _
                           clsFunctions.GetActualTableName(Me.Name, "Companies") & " Companies " & _
                           " WHERE fid.CompanyCode = Companies.CompanyCode "

                    If Not strSelectedCompanies.Equals(String.Empty) Then
                        objDBcommand.CommandText &= " AND fid.companycode IN ( " & strSelectedCompanies & ")"
                    End If

                    objDBcommand.CommandText &= " GROUP BY FID.CompanyCode, Fid.subAccountCode " & _
                       " ) H " & _
                       " where Voy.Voyagecode = b.SubAccountCode " & _
                       " AND b.CompanyCode = Voy.Vesselcode " & _
                       " AND voy.VesselCode = Comp.Companycode " & _
                      " AND voy.VesselCode = H.Companycode " & _
                       " AND H.SubAccountCode  = b.SubAccountCode "

                    If Not strSelectedCompanies.Equals(String.Empty) Then
                        objDBcommand.CommandText &= " AND voy.VesselCode IN ( " & strSelectedCompanies & ")"
                    End If


                    If Not txtVoyage.CodeText.Equals(String.Empty) OrElse txtVoyage.cboSelectedItems.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
                        objDBcommand.CommandText &= " AND Voy.VoyageCode"
                        If Not txtVoyage.CodeText.Equals(String.Empty) Then
                            objDBcommand.CommandText &= " = " & clsGlobals.Q(txtVoyage.CodeText)
                        Else
                            objDBcommand.CommandText &= " IN " & clsFunctions.CriteriaValuesFromRowsCollection(CType(txtVoyage.cboSelectedItems.DataSource, DataSet).Tables(0).Rows, txtVoyage.CodeFieldName)
                        End If
                    End If

                    objDBcommand.CommandText &= ")a left outer Join " & _
                    "(  " & _
                         " select case " & _
                            " when Links.CalculationType = 1 then 0 " & _
                             " when Links.CalculationType = 2 then 1 " & _
                                 " else -1 " & _
                                " end as TimeCharterInd, " & _
                                 " Links.CalculationType, Links.amountCode, Links.AmountDescription, Links.AccountCode " & _
                                 " FROM " & _
                                  "( " & _
                                     " select AL.AmountCode , S.AmountDescription , AL.AccountCode,Al.CalculationType  " & _
                                   " from sea_VoyageEstimationAmounts s, ActualLinks AL " & _
                                                  " where al.AmountCode = s.AmountCode " & _
                                " )Links " & _
                            " )b on a.TimeCharterInd = b.TimecharterInd " & _
                               " and a.AccountCode = b.AccountCode " & _
                                " order by a.companyCode, a.AccountCode "

                    objDBcommand.Execute(SearchDS)
```

Here is the SQL part:

```
SELECT a.*,
   isNull(b.CalculationType, 0) AS CalculationType,
   isnull(b.amountCode, 0) AS AmountCode,
   isNull(b.AmountDescription, '') AS AmountDescription INTO
FROM (
SELECT isnull(VEE.TotalDelaysDuration, 0) AS TotalDays,
       isnull(VEE.TCE, 0) AS NetProfitEstimated,
       Comp.CompanyCode,
       Comp.Description AS CompanyDescription,
       b.AccountCode,
       b.AccountDescription,
       CASE
           WHEN (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC) > 0 THEN (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC)
           ELSE 0
       END AS AmountDebitBC,
       CASE
           WHEN (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC) < 0 THEN (b.AmountDebitBC - b.AmountCreditBC)
           ELSE 0
       END AS AmountCreditBC,
       Voy.CharterPartyDate,
       Voy.VoyageCode,
       Voy.Description,
       Voy.TimeCharterInd,
       Voy.StartDateTime,
       Voy.LastVoyageTerminationDateTime,
       H.LastHireDateTime,
       CASE
           WHEN Voy.TimeCharterInd = 1 THEN Voy.Hire
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN Voy.TimeCharterInd = 0 THEN CASE
                                                         WHEN voy.FreightRate <> 0 THEN voy.FreightRate
                                                         ELSE CASE
                                                                  WHEN voy.TotalFreight <> 0 THEN voy.TotalFreight
                                                                  ELSE 0
                                                              END
                                                     END
                END
       END AS Hire,
       CASE
           WHEN Voy.TimeCharterInd = 0 THEN CASE
                                                WHEN voy.FreightRate <> 0 THEN 1
                                                ELSE CASE
                                                         WHEN voy.TotalFreight <> 0 THEN 2
                                                         ELSE 0
                                                     END
                                            END
           ELSE 0
       END ValueFreight,
       Voy.Commission,
       voy.ActualEndDateTime,
       BP.Name,
       CASE
           WHEN Voy.lastVoyageTerminationDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN (CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)) - CAST(Voy.lastVoyageTerminationDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)))
           ELSE 0
       END AS BallastDays,
       isnull(CASE
                  WHEN voy.ActualEndDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN voy.ActualEndDateTime
                  WHEN voy.EstimatedEndDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN voy.EstimatedEndDateTime
              END, 0) AS TerminatedDate,
       CASE
           WHEN voy.ActualEndDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 0
           WHEN voy.EstimatedEndDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1
       END AS ActualOrEstimated,
       CASE
           WHEN Voy.TimeCharterInd = 1.0 THEN CASE
                                                  WHEN voy.ActualEndDateTime = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN CASE
                                                                                                              WHEN H.LastHireDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN CAST(H.LastHireDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)) - CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2))
                                                                                                              ELSE 0
                                                                                                          END
                                                  ELSE CAST(voy.ActualEndDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)) - CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2))
                                              END
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN voy.ActualEndDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN CAST(Voy.ActualEndDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)) - CAST(Voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2))
                    ELSE CASE
                             WHEN voy.EstimatedEndDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN CAST(voy.EstimatedEndDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)) - CAST(voy.StartDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2))
                             ELSE 0
                         END
                END
       END AS 'Voyage Period',
       CASE
           WHEN Voy.TimeCharterInd = 1
                AND H.LastHireDateTime <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN CAST(H.LastHireDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2)) - CAST(lastVoyageTerminationDateTime AS NUMERIC(9, 2))
           ELSE 0
       END AS 'Hire Collected'
FROM voyages voy
LEFT OUTER JOIN VoyagesEstimationHeader VEE ON VEE.VoyageCode = voy.Voyagecode
AND VEE.VesselCode = voy.Vesselcode
AND VEE.EstimationStatus = '3'
AND VEE.PrevailingInd = (CASE
                             WHEN (
                                     (SELECT count(*)
                                      FROM VoyagesEstimationHeader
                                      WHERE vesselcode = VEE.VesselCode
                                        AND VoyageCode = VEE.VoyageCode
                                        AND EstimationStatus = '3') > 1) THEN 1
                             ELSE
                                    (SELECT PrevailingInd
                                     FROM VoyagesEstimationHeader
                                     WHERE vesselcode = VEE.VesselCode
                                       AND VoyageCode = VEE.VoyageCode
                                       AND EstimationStatus = '3')
                         END)
LEFT OUTER JOIN BusinessPartners BP ON Voy.ChartererCode = BP.BusinessPartnerCode,
                                       Companies Comp, (
SELECT Fid.AccountCode,
       Acc.Description AS AccountDescription,
       FID.SubAccountCode,
       FID.CompanyCode,
       sum(Fid.AmountDebitBC)AS 'AmountDebitBC',
       sum(Fid.AmountCreditBC) AS 'AmountCreditBC'
FROM FiStatementsDetail FID,
     FiStatementsHeader FIH,
     Accounts Acc,
     Companies Companies
WHERE Fid.AccountCode = acc.AccountCode
  AND Acc.SubAccountType = 2
  AND Fid.TransactionType = FiH.TransactionType
  AND Fid.TransactionNum = FiH.TransactionNum
  AND Fid.FiscalYear = FiH.FiscalYear
  AND FiH.TransactionReasonCode NOT IN ('YP',
                                        'YC')
  AND FID.CompanyCode = Companies.CompanyCode
```

Comment: Please post the actual SQL being executed. It's difficult to debug it as you are showing it.

Comment: I apologize, I updated the post

Comment: `AS AmountDescription INTO
FROM (` looks like you were planning to store this data somewhere (using `INTO`), but forgot to say *where*.

Comment: Evolve! Old-style comma joins were replaced 30 years ago. You seem to have some missing brackets or logic at the end of the query, there is now some weird cross-join going on. Also, the bit `VEE.PrevailingInd = (CASE WHEN ((SELECT count(*)....` is probably better with a window function